# SqLite3: как подсчитать количество возвращаемых строк?

Tags: php, sqlite3

Есть простейший скрипт поиска в БД. Он работает, но невозможно подсчитать количество найденных результатов. Ищет он в двух столбцах — title и content

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title LIKE '%$search%' OR content LIKE '%$search%'.
```

На сколько мне известно, во второй версии sqlite была функция SQLiteResult::numRows, а в sqlite3 её нет. Зачем её убрали? Лулзов ради?

Подскажите, как подсчитать число строк.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Варианты

**SQL**:

```
$row = $db->querySingle("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM articles WHERE title LIKE '%$search%' OR content LIKE '%$search%'");
echo $row;
```

---

**PHP**

```
if($stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title LIKE '%$search%' OR content LIKE '%$search%'")){
        $results = $stmt->execute();
        $rowCount = 0; // Count Rows
    while ($row = $results->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)){
        ++$rowCount;
    }
    echo $rowCount;
}
```

[Собственно вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586598/using-sqlite3-in-php-how-to-count-the-number-of-rows-in-a-result-set)

---

**UPD:**

```
// Count rows from select
$count_row = $db->querySingle("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM articles WHERE title LIKE '%$search%' OR content LIKE '%$search%'");
if($count_row > 0){
  // Table is not empty
  $results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title LIKE '%$search%' OR content LIKE '%$search%'");
  while ($row = $results->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
    var_dump($row);
  }
}else{
 // Empty table message
}
```

Comment: `if($stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title LIKE '%$search%' OR content LIKE '%$search%'")){
  $results = $stmt->execute();
  $rowCount = 0;
    if($rowCount > 0) {
     while ($row = $results->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {  
      ++$rowCount;
      echo $search . ' найдено ' . $rowCount . '<br />
      id: ' . $row['id'] . '<br /> Дата: ' . $row['datetime'] . '<br /> Заголовок: ' . $row['title'] . '<br /> Катег.: ' . $row['category'] . '<br /> Конт.: ' . $row['content'] . '<br />';
     }
    }
    else {
     echo 'Не найдено';
     echo $rowCount;
    }
}`

Comment: Так не работает( Не выводит «Не найдено» Прошу прощения за плохое форматирование и отсутствие табуляции, не позволяет редактор сайта.

Comment: @Linne `$rowCount = 0;` никак не может быть в тоже время равен, чему-то что больше `нуля`.

Comment: Блин, точно))) Вот я лопух) А как проверить тогда?

Comment: @Linne Если, помогло примите Ответ.

Comment: Нет, к сожалению не помогло, хотя, может быть, просто я криворукий. Не удаётся применить это в моём случае. Необходимо, чтобы подсчитывалось число строк, после чего сформировать условие, при котором если число больше ноля, то выводим результаты, если меньше, то выводим сообщение, что результатов нет. Подскажите, как это реализовать в моём случае?

Comment: @Linne Попробуйте так.

Comment: Да! Так работает! Огромное вам спасибо!

Answer (score -2):

```
$sql=$dbase->query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title LIKE '%$search%' OR content LIKE '%$search%';");
$n=0; while($z=$sql->fetchArray()) {$n++;}
```

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/335314)

Comment: @vmchar но ведь содержится